Bijection Defined by Limit of Maximal Solutions
I need help to solve the following problem.

Let $F: \mathbb{R}^{1+d} \to \mathbb{R}^d$ be a continuos function which is locally Lipschitz in the second variable, and suppose that there exists a continuous function $g\colon [0, +\infty) \to [0, +\infty) $ such that $\int_0^{+\infty} g(s)\, ds < + \infty$ and $||F(t,x)|| \leq g(t) ||x||, \, \forall t \geq 0$ and $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^d$.


Show that the maximal solution $\gamma_{x_0}$ of $x' = F(t,x)$ with any initial condition $\gamma_{x_0}(0) = x_0$ is defined for all $t \in [0,+\infty)$ and it has a limit as $t \to +\infty$.
Assuming that $||F(t,x) - F(t,y)|| \leq g(t) ||x-y||$ for all $t \geq 0$ and $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, show that the function $x_0 \mapsto \lim_{t \to +\infty} \gamma_{x_0}(t)$ is a bijection on $\mathbb{R}$.

I think I managed to do the first problem. So the function $z\colon x_0 \in \mathbb{R} \mapsto \lim_{t \to +\infty} \gamma_{x_0}(t)$ is well defined. My idea for proving the second problem was to prove some regularity about $z$ (like strictly monotonic). But I'm struggling in how to do it. What I was able to do was, for all $x_0, y_0 \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$ z(x_0) = z(y_0) \Leftrightarrow \lim_{t \to +\infty} | \gamma_{x_0}(t) - \gamma_{y_0}(t) | = 0,$$
and, by Gronwall Lemma, for all $t \in [0, +\infty)$,
$$ | \gamma_{x_0}(t) - \gamma_{y_0}(t) | \leq |x_0 - y_0| + \int_0^t g(s) |\gamma_{x_0}(s) - \gamma_{y_0}(s) |\, ds \leq |x_0 - y_0| \exp\left(\int_0^t g(s)\, ds\right).$$
As this integral is finite as $t$ goes to infinity, we conclude that $z$ is a Lipschitz function.
Is this approach right?
Thanks.

Where does this question come form? Is this a homework question?

@KevinDietrich Yes. Is an exercise from the book Differential Equations: A Dynamical Systems Approach to Theory and Practice of M. Viana and J. Espinar.
